# IntelliJ IDEA, xml name spaces for urn:java?

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, xml-namespaces

I'd like to get IntelliJ to recognize and read the classpath for name spaces in my `web.xml` or other xml files.

For example:

```xml
<whatever:HeartbeatService xmlns:heartbeat="urn:java:whatever">
    <ee:Named xmlns:ee="urn:java:ee">HeartbeatService</ee:Named>
    <inject:Singleton xmlns:inject="urn:java:javax.inject"/>
</whatever:HeartbeatService>
```

IntelliJ displays `urn:java:whatever`, `urn:java:ee` and `urn:java:javax.inject` in red, with the error message: "URI is not registered (Settings | Project Settings | Schemas and DTDs)".

Perhaps there is some way to register the class path that I'm just missing?

Comment: @ danieljimenez: Please note the change in tags. Please let revert if you disagree.

Answer (score 1):

Alt+Enter on top of the red namespace declaration and then "Manually Setup External Resource".

Comment: 1- It's not an external resource, it's internal (in the class path) 2- If this is the place to do it, how do you point to the class path? Down voting bc you didn't take the time to understand the question.

Comment: The closest I can see is http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/referencing-dtd-or-schema.html#2, which says how you can map a local file. I don't see anything referencing classpath, but you may be able to do it from there.

Comment: @danieljimenez how about XML catalog? Settings -> Schemas and DTDs -> XML Catalog. That is probably closest what you can get..

Comment: I do not have an 'XML Catalog' option in my Intellij (v 13)